# Number of ways to represent an integer as sum of integers

Tags: combinatorics

I was wondering if there is a formula to calculate the number of ways to represents a positive integer as sum of integers. For example $5$:

$$ 5=5\\ 5=4+1\\ 5=3+2\\ 5=3+1+1\\ 5=2+2+1\\ 5=2+1+1+1\\ 5=1+1+1+1+1 $$

so $7$ ways. It probably was already asked but I couldn't find the related question.

Comment: Google: Integer partitions.  Although there are recursive formulas and an asymptotic expansion, there is actually no "closed form" formula for this.  It's similar to how there's no formula for the $n$-th prime.

Comment: Also, recently people have found an [algebraic formula](https://www.aimath.org/news/partition/brunier-ono.pdf) and a [combinatorial formula](http://home.dimacs.rutgers.edu/~asills/Durfee/CholiySillsRevAOC.pdf).  But these are quite advanced...

Answer (score 1):

This is the number of partitions of a positive integer $n,$ and there are recursive formulas to calculate this number.